# Ajax PHP upload

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

I need to upload file with ajax.
 Is there any method to send files using ajax but only not by flash.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for any modern browser apart from IE.

Bascially you need to get Javascript to load the file (see [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)). You can then use that data to post it through AJAX.

Comment: Did you mean 'any modern browser'?

Comment: Yes - will edit (perhaps sensible instead or modern!?)

Answer (score -2):

It isn't possible to send files with AJAX.

Comment: I know that in ajax there are only two methods post and get but in there any possibility to send the form with ajax request I think there must be any way

Comment: The [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) provided by Daniil suggests otherwise.